# During or since

Tags: prepositions

I expect to return from Singapore during about a week's time

I think the above sentence is incorrect because **during** is wrongly used, instead of this **within** should be used.

Am I right?

Comment: Why do you think that? In a week is not within a week.

Comment: Because I may return earlier

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Assuming you mean to say that you'll be returning from Singapore in up to a week, you'll want to use **within** instead. I would also lose the *'s time* and *about* parts, so the phrase looks like this:

> I expect to return from Singapore **within** a week.